# Use Ansible filters with jinja2-cli

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, jinja2-cli

I'm trying to use Ansible filters with the Jinja2 CLI from github.com/mattrobenolt/jinja2-cli. It expects an extension that is passed to jinja2.Environment constructor.
I tried to search in the function (`password_hash`) I want to use in the Ansible repo : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f270b4e224174557963120e75bfc81acf1cdde61/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L625
But I wasn't able to figure out how to add it to the Jinja2 CLI. Is it even possible without rewriting some code?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think [someone heard your pleas](https://github.com/mattrobenolt/jinja2-cli/pull/104) so keep an eye on that PR!